# using expo-print and getting this error -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Orientation' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo

Im using expo SDK 49 on my expo managed react-native project.

If I include import statement
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J33Q1.png)

Then this error gets immediately thrown when the app is run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Orientation' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Has anyone faced this issue

Tried upgrading to expo SDK 49, and also tried reinstalling node modules. Error still persists

Comment: It would be more conveniënt for us if the code is directly pasted as text/formatted code. rather than images. That would make it easier to search for keywords or test it out ourselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

I was running on expo dev mode. When using packages that rely on native modules, I have to build the package again with eas build --profile development --platform android